# ASPx GridView - multiple Detail Row User Controls with Client Side Events

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I have A Callback enabled DevExpress ASPxGridView with a user control within the detail row template.

The user control performs CRUD operations and is also callback enabled, using a HiddenField controller to capture control changes. It also has save and cancel buttons.

When I expand n detail rows, the ClientInstanceName for the hidden field controller is replicated n times and all client side control manipulation targets the last expanded detail rows control's hidden field.

Is there any way of coding the markup and JavaScript so client side control manipulation only target's it's own hidden field instance? - Specifically without dynamically adding JavaScript and ClientSideEvents via my C# code behind?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution would be to set the ClientInstanceName and write the corresponding client side code in the HtmlRowCreated event handler of the ASPxGridView.